# Multiplying by Diagonal Matrix On Top of Standard Linear Regression

Tags: linear-regression, backpropagation, linear-algebra

In minimizing
$$min_x||Ax-b||$$
where $A$ is overdetermined, one could use least squares method.  However, if there is another diagonal matrix $d$ which has $k$ unique entries along the diagonal with $k << dim(A)$, how would one go about minimizing
$$min_{d,x}||dAx-b||$$